# Yocto Raspberry Pi Change psplash image

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, splash-screen, yocto, meta-raspberrypi

I've successfully built a raspberry pi Yocto image using the instructions here: http://www.jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Raspberry-Pi-Systems-with-Yocto.html. When the system boots, I see the default psplash splash screen of a Raspberry Pi with a loading bar.

The meta-raspberrypi layer has a psplash bbappend recipe file that defines the raspberry pi image seen when the system boots.

```
me@me:~/poky-morty/meta-raspberrypi$ grep -R SPLASH *
conf/machine/include/rpi-base.inc:SPLASH = "psplash-raspberrypi"
recipes-core/images/rpi-basic-image.bb:SPLASH = "psplash-raspberrypi"
recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bbappend:SPLASH_IMAGES += "file://psplash-raspberrypi-img.h;outsuffix=raspberrypi"
```

The SPLASH variable in dpi-base.inc defines the splash screen to use ( I think... ) and the psplash_git.bbappend file pretends the image with the matching out suffix of raspberry pi.

The bbappend looks like this:

```
me@me:~/poky-morty/meta-raspberrypi$ cat recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bbappend
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SPLASH_IMAGES += "file://psplash-raspberrypi-img.h;outsuffix=raspberrypi"
```

I have a custom layer and I made another psplash_git.bbappend in that layer with the following contents - attempting to override the image used for the raspberry pi splash screen with my own image:

```
me@me:~/rpi/meta-me/recipes-me/psplash$ cat psplash_git.bbappend 
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SPLASH_IMAGES += "file://social.jpg-img.h;outsuffix=raspberrypi"
```

If I try to build my image with my custom bbappend included, I get the following error:

```
Initialising tasks: 100% |##################################| Time: 0:00:05
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: psplash-0.1+gitAUTOINC+88343ad23c-r15 do_package: QA Issue: psplash-raspberrypi is listed in PACKAGES multiple times, this leads to packaging errors. [packages-list]
ERROR: psplash-0.1+gitAUTOINC+88343ad23c-r15 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: psplash-0.1+gitAUTOINC+88343ad23c-r15 do_package: Function failed: do_package
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/me/rpi/build/tmp/work/arm1176jzfshf-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/psplash/0.1+gitAUTOINC+88343ad23c-r15/temp/log.do_package.63289
ERROR: Task (/home/me/poky-morty/meta/recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3439 tasks of which 3430 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

I get the same error ( duplicate target ) if I change the outsuffix to default.

I can get around this error by changing my bbappend to this:

```
me@me:~/rpi/meta-me/recipes-me/psplash$ cat psplash_git.bbappend 
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SPLASH_IMAGES += "file://social.jpg-img.h;outsuffix=me"
```

And then I try to override the SPLASH configuration variable in my local.conf like this:

```
# Set the Custom Splash screen
SPLASH = "psplash-me"
```

But no matter what I seem to do, it always renders the default Raspberry Pi one.

How can I override the default psplash splash screen with my own image? Thanks.

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [**Raspberry pi StackExchange**](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Though that is a judgment call since this is tangentially coding related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the file should match the format `psplash-%s` where `%s` is `raspberrypi` so the quickest way is to change your `social.jpg-img.h` to `psplash-raspberrypi-img.h` and overwrite it on the original raspberrypi psplash.bbappend.

Below is information on how it gets the `outsuffix` variable;

```
for uri in splashfiles:
        fetcher = bb.fetch2.Fetch([uri], d)
        flocal = os.path.basename(fetcher.localpath(uri))
        fbase = os.path.splitext(flocal)[0]
        outsuffix = fetcher.ud[uri].parm.get("outsuffix")
        if not outsuffix:
            if fbase.startswith("psplash-"):
                outsuffix = fbase[8:]
            else:
                outsuffix = fbase
            if outsuffix.endswith('-img'):
                outsuffix = outsuffix[:-4]
        outname = "psplash-%s" % outsuffix
        if outname == '' or outname in oldpkgs:
            bb.fatal("The output name '%s' derived from the URI %s is not valid, please specify the outsuffix parameter" % (outname, uri))
        else:
            pkgs.append(outname)
        if flocal.endswith(".png"):
            haspng = True
        localpaths.append(flocal)
```

`SPLASH_IMAGES` is basically map of files that has key with `outsuffix`.

```
SPLASH_IMAGES = "file://splash-file-one.h;outsuffix=one \
                       file://splash-file-two.h;outsuffix=two"
```

This will automatically create psplash- packages for each splash image entry (i.e. psplash-one and psplash-two).

> splash: Enables showing a splash screen during boot. By default, this
>   screen is provided by psplash, which does allow customization. If you
>   prefer to use an alternative splash screen package, you can do so by
>   setting the SPLASH variable to a different package name (or names)
>   within the image recipe or at the distro configuration level.

Instead of using default, raspberrypi provides alternative to choose the splash image in the machine configuration; This link gives more information
https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-May/013902.html

```
+# Set raspberrypi splash image
+SPLASH = "psplash-raspberrypi"
diff --git a/recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bbappend b/recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bbappend
index eea8dfb..65dc30f 100644
--- a/recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bbappend
+++ b/recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bbappend
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
-SPLASH_IMAGES = "file://psplash-raspberrypi-img.h;outsuffix=default"
+SPLASH_IMAGES += "file://psplash-raspberrypi-img.h;outsuffix=raspberrypi"
-- 
1.8.2.2
```

Comment: Lets say I've build two splash package splash-file-one.rpm for 10" display resolution@800x600 and splash-file-two.rpm for 7" display resolution@800x480  ,  is there a way to select & load one of these two package runtime on target according to connected display resolution found [Run time package management ], Or just install manually & should reflect on next boot ?

Answer (score 3):

As [Charles C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788396/yocto-raspberry-pi-change-psplash-image/45806792#45806792) mentioned, one way is to overwrite `psplash-raspberrypi-img.h`

> And then I try to override the SPLASH configuration variable in my local.conf like this:
> `# Set the Custom Splash screen`
> `SPLASH = "psplash-me"`
> But no matter what I seem to do, it always renders the default Raspberry Pi one.

Theoretically it should be enough just to set
`psplash_%.bbappend`:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SPLASH_IMAGES_append = " file://foo-img.png;outsuffix=bar"
```

`conf/local.conf`:

```
SPLASH = " psplash-bar"
```

just as [it is done in `meta-raspberry`](https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi/blob/a34a6d9eaf375cf29c800a5a770cc449bf119a1d/recipes-core/psplash/psplash_%25.bbappend) but it seems that `meta-raspberry` [is setting `SPLASH` inside image definition](https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi/blob/a34a6d9eaf375cf29c800a5a770cc449bf119a1d/recipes-core/images/rpi-basic-image.bb#L9) class and that overwrites you value from `local.conf`

At this point it is worth to see how it is evalueated:

```
bitbake -e core-image-base | less
```

and search for `^SPLASH` you will notice that it has final value `psplash-raspberrypi`.

#### solution

This is how I managed to make it work:

`psplash_%.bbappend`:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SPLASH_IMAGES_append = " file://foo-img.png;outsuffix=bar"
ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY_psplash-bar[psplash] = "200"
```

`conf/local.conf`:

```
PACKAGE_INSTALL_append = " psplash-bar"
```

#### what happens here:

`SPLASH_IMAGES_append = " file://foo-img.png;outsuffix=bar"`
This will produce package `psplash-bar`. You can provide `.png` and it will be converted to appropriate header file, but you can also provide raw header. psplash receipe will deduce it.

`PACKAGE_INSTALL_append = " psplash-bar"`
This will tell bitbake to install it on rootfs, (if `SPLASH` weren't overwritten, then it would be evaluated [here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/image.bbclass?h=dunfell&id=35cc7fef84b986c1893c80c75dc057e002a2357f#n57))

at this point after building image `psplash-bar` will be installed on rootfs, but `psplash` won't be linked to it:

```
ls -lh /usr/bin/psplash*
lrwxrwxrwx psplash -> /usr/bin/psplash-raspberrypi
-rwxr-xr-x psplash-raspberrypi
-rwxr-xr-x psplash-systemd
-rwxr-xr-x psplash-bar
-rwxr-xr-x psplash-write
```

So that with this:
`ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY_psplash-bar[psplash] = "200"`
we will tell `bibtake` to use `psplash-bar` to be alternative package (provider?) with priority 200.

```
ls -lh /usr/bin/psplash*
lrwxrwxrwx psplash -> /usr/bin/psplash-bar
-rwxr-xr-x psplash-raspberrypi
-rwxr-xr-x psplash-systemd
-rwxr-xr-x psplash-bar
-rwxr-xr-x psplash-write
```

Comment: Followed this answer, but running `ls -lh /usr/bin/psplash*` only give me: `psplash -> /usr/bin/psplash-raspberrypi psplash-raspberrypi psplash-write` Any tips or ideas? Am I correct to use `build/conf/local.conf` and `meta-my\recipes-my\my\psplash_%.bbappend`?

Comment: As I understood you can't see your psplash on filesystem at all. It looks like `SPLASH_IMAGES_append` is not taking effect, because it should trigger custom splash build. you can add some logging to `psplash_%.bbappend` to see if it is parsed/loaded correctly. It is always worth to grep through `bitbake -e ...` output for your splash name etc

Answer (score 1):

**A simple solution**

1. Clone [meta-splash](https://github.com/hamzamac/meta-splash) layer in your Poky project: `git clone https://github.com/hamzamac/meta-splash.git`
2. Replace the default `logo.png` image with your logo image with name `logo.png` (the name can be customized in `customize.bb`)
3. Bake your image

That is all

To customize the colors, check the meta-splash's [README](https://github.com/hamzamac/meta-splash)